# Java simple recursion explanation

Tags: java, recursion

I was implementing a very simple recursive method to multiply two numbers together. I am very a hard time understanding the basics of recursion.

Is anyone able to explain to me (Line-by-line if possible) how this code works? I am especially confused about the base case is written to return 0 when in reality the actual multiplication is returned instead.

```
    public static int multiply(int n, int m) {
    if (m == 0) {
        return 0; //Base case
    }
    return multiply(n, m - 1) + n; //Recursive Case - Decrements m, while adding n
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Well, try to reason through it yourself: you call the method and unless the second parameter is 0 (which would mean the result is 0 anyway) you call the method again and add `n` to the result. This basically builds a stack of calls with decreasing values of `m` until you hit 0. This is done to not go on indefinitely but would break for negative `m` values.

Comment: One way of making recursion more understandable might be via ["Inception"](https://medium.com/@arnoldom23/inception-with-recursion-dc73a2c32f11) (the movie): `enterDream(person) { if(!inLImbo) enterDream(person.getDream().getDreamingCharacter())) }`

Comment: How does the 'return 0' not overwrite multiply() call's stacks of 'n' when 'm' reaches the base case of 0?  Basically, how is the multiplication returned and not the 0 from the return 0?

Comment: Well, the call `multiply(n, 0)` _will_ return 0 and not call `multiply(n, -1)` so the recursion ends there. Then that 0 will be added to `n` and the result is returned to `multiply(n, 1)` where another `n` is added. So in the end `multiply(n, m)` adds `n` to `0` (the last element) `m` times and thus yields the same result as `n * m`. - One note though: returning `n` when `m == 1` would yield the same result and have one less recursive call. Why `m == 0` has been selected is up to design and probably meant to make the alogrithm easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to make this answer beginner friendly. First I will answer this part of your question:

> *I am especially confused about the base case is written to return 0
> when in reality the actual multiplication is returned instead.*

*The value returned in the base case depends on how you are implementing your algorithm*. Here in order to calculate `n*m`, we extend this multiplication to addition. A few examples will make this more clear.

```
2*3 = 2 + 2 + 2 + 0
4*1 = 4 + 0
5*5 = 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 0
n*m = n + n + n + ... + (m times) + 0
```

*That is why we return 0 in the base case, we have to stop the recursion without making any change in the result and that is only possible if we add 0*.

---

Here is the working of this program:

```
public static int multiply(int n, int m) {
if (m == 0) {
    return 0; //Base case
}
return multiply(n, m - 1) + n;
```

Let us take `n = 4` and `m = 3`.

Our first call to the method is `multiply(4, 3)`. We then proceed further, the base condition is false so we skip that.

We then get to this part: `return multiply(n, m - 1) + n`. We make another call to the same function. `multiple(4, 2)`. Again we skip the base case. Here is a table:

```
multiply(4, 3) -> return multiply (4, 2) + 4
multiple(4, 2) -> return multiply (4, 1) + 4
multiple(4, 1) -> return multiply (4, 0) + 4
multiple(4, 0) -> 0
```

On substituting the returned values we get,

```
multiple(4, 3) -> return 0 + 4 + 4 + 4 
multiple(4, 2) -> return 0 + 4 + 4
multiple(4, 1) -> return 0 + 4
multiple(4, 0) -> return 0
```

If our first call is `multiply(n, m)`, then the end returned value is:

```
multiply (n, m) -> return 0 + n + n + n + ... + (m times)
```

*I hope I have helped you. Try to construct a similar relation like this on your own and you will understand it better.* Here is a link on further explanation on recursion:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion